# Need help getting the output of a for loop into Excel/CSV using OS.WALK

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, os.walk

> Need help with getting the printed output to a CSV/Excel file.

Thanks for your help!

```
import pandas as pd
import os


for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))

#Need to print the results of this search into an excel/csv File.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to add the lines to a list, and then create a dataframe from it and write it to a file. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

l = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             l.append(os.path.join(root, file))

pd.DataFrame(l).to_excel(r"C:\Users\______\Desktop\filelist.xlsx", index=False)
```

If you need a CSV file, use `pandas.to_csv(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I am trying to piece it together one step at a time!

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

we can recursively search your directory for all excels and print the results to a data frame,

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

excels = [f for f in Path(r"C:/").rglob('*.xlsx')] # might take a while.
# remove r if you're not on windows.


name = [f.stem for f in excels]
absoloute_path = [f.absolute() for f in excels]
parent = [f.parent for f in excels]
home = [f.home() for f in excels]
parents = {k.stem:'-->'.join([str(i) for i in k.parents][::-1]) for k in excels}

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : name,
            'abs' : absoloute_path,
             'parent' : parent,
             'home' : home})


final = pd.concat(
    [
        df.set_index("name"),
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parents, orient="index", columns=["parents"]),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Final will be a dataframe with the file name, absolute path, parent, home & parent structure dentoed by `C:/ -- > C:/foo ---> C:/foo/bar`

you can then export this to excel using `final.to_excel`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will take time to understand this completely!

Comment: @HKDK no problem, did the code work on your machine?